# Multiple linear models and multiple comparison correction

Tags: mixed-model, pca, multiple-comparisons

I have run a PCA from which I have extracted 4 components. Each component will be used in a multilevel model as the outcome variable. The four model will have the exact same predictor variables, 4 predictors of interest and age and gender to adjust for. ID is a random factor.
My question is how do I have to correct for multiple comparisons, is each model a comparison or would each variable within each model be a comparison (so 24 comparison in total)?
I want to extract from each model the significant predictors for each PCA component but first i want to correct the p values I am just unsure of how any comparisons I have. The other possibility is 32 comparison I think.

Answer (score 0):

TL DR: Don't do any variable selection and don't do any adjustment for multiple comparisons.

Longer answer:

Regarding adjustments for multiple comparisons in general, I like what Jacob Cohen said, many years ago:

> This is a subject about which reasonable people may differ.

But regarding your particular problem, you wrote

> I want to extract from each model the significant predictors for each
> PCA component

and also

> 4 predictors of interest and age and gender to adjust for

so my recommendation (provided that you have a reasonable sized sample) is to *not* extract certain predictors. Why not?

First: You have a strong *a priori* hypothesis. Stick with it. This is the best situation to be in.

Second: For your variables of interest, you are interested in them, whether they are significant or not. You didn't give us context, but, with variables of interest, finding a small effect can often be as important as finding a big one (and never mind all the problems with significance). Finding a small effect would be surprising and, as my favorite prof in grad school said:

> If you're not surprised, you haven't learned anything.

Third: For age and sex (I'm guessing it is sex, not gender) these are variables you want to adjust for. That is important whether or not they are significant. They may have big effects on the other parameter estimates. Or they might not. But that might also be surprising and interesting.

And the other benefit is that, with these a priori hypotheses, I think you can make a strong case for not adjusting at all.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to clarify to see if I understood you right (probably not hahah). You say I shouldn't do correction for multiple comparisons and instead of only extracting the variables that do have a significant effect, to extract all of them from all the models? In that case I wouldn't be picking out only the significant ones. Ket me know if I got it right!

Comment: Yes, that's right.